# How to move to other activity

Tags: java, android

This is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/background">
<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_activity_1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/Activity_2"
android:onClick="onClick" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_activity_2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/Activity_3"
android:onClick="onClick" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now i want that whenever i click on `btn_activity_1` it should move to the other activity which is name with `countrylist` , i mention my other activity in `manifest.xml`

Manifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name="././..MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="././..countrylist"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

This is what i learn that when i click on `btn_activity_1` it should move to the next activity `countrylist`

```
Intent k = new Intent(this.MainActivity, countrylist.class);
    startActivity(k);
    //finish();
    break;
```

But as I am very new to android house , I don't know how/where I apply the case that when I click on `btn_activity_1` it should move to other but when `btn_activity_2` it do some other task

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, i hope this will resolve your issue:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

              Intent browserIntent = 
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.mkyong.com"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);

            }

        });

    }

}
```